# IIS 8 video streaming concurrency

Tags: asp.net, video, video-streaming, iis-8.5

I'm developing .NET video streaming service and for hosting I use dedicated server with IIS 8.5.
For streaming I use ASP.NET Web API (http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/ - this article helped me) and everything works fine.
But when multiple users are watching one video file concurrently, IIS throw this issue:
**The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\VideolessonVideos\videofilename.mp4' because it is being used by another process.**

On my local machine (not dedicated server) this issue does not occur - multiple users can watch one video concurrently.

I think this is because wrong IIS configuration but I don't know exactly what to configure.

Can everyone help me?

Thanks,
Mikhail